# Find a stored procedure name with its content in SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2000

For a stored procedure, I have its full source code. But the **name** of that stored procedure has been lost. In this database, there are hundreds of stored procedures.

So is there a way by which I can find out the **name** of the stored procedure by using its contents or by using any of the variables in the contents?

This is puzzling me a lot. A help would be sincerley appreciated.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try this:

```
select * from sysobjects where id in 
(select id from syscomments where text like '%exec%')
order by [name]
```

where 'exec' is the text you're searching for. This query will search views also, just fyi

Answer (score 6):

If the texts of the stored procedures are not encrypted, Sql Server keeps the full text of the procedure in the `syscomments` table with an `id` field that is referencing the `sysobjects` table, where the actual name is stored.

So, find some representative line from the stored procedure, that is unlikely to be in another place, and do:

```
select o.name, c.text 
from syscomments c
   inner join sysobjects o on o.id = c.id
where c.text like '%<representative_line>%'
  and o.type='P' -- this means filter procedures only
```

This should hopefully return just a few procedures that you can check by hand.

Comment: this is also good. But can't select more than one 'Answer'. Thnaks : )

Answer (score 2):

There is another approach, more readable and memorable:

```
SELECT ROUTINE_NAME, ROUTINE_DEFINITION 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES 
    WHERE ROUTINE_DEFINITION LIKE '%AlgunaPalabraQueTeAcuerdes%' 
    AND ROUTINE_TYPE='PROCEDURE'
```

This works at least in sql 2008 and newer versions. [Fuente](http://www.marioperez.com.mx/blog/find-stored-procedure-full-text/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this Query it will get the Procedure Name that contains the Given word or Field

```
   SELECT Name 
        FROM sys.procedures 
        WHERE OBJECT_DEFINITION(object_id) LIKE '%Any-Field (OR) WORD%'
```

Comment: sys.procedures doesn't exist on SQL 2000

Comment: True. Mentioned Prob is for SQL 2000 !!

Answer (score 0):

```
select object_name(id) from syscomments where text like '%exec%'
```